# Not authority of deployed program

Tags: solana-program, deploy

I deployed a program from the command line, but when checking the program data, there is no associated authority, and I'm unable to close the program, and the rent is locked up. Is there a way to avoid this?

Edit: I just realized this was because I did solana deploy instead of solana program deploy... hopefully there's a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `solana deploy` instead of `solana program deploy`, the program was uploaded to the BPF Loader instead of the Upgradeable BPF Loader, so it is forever immutable, and there's no way to change it.

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed program using `solana deploy ...` then you will be asked to provide signer in the command. If you don't provide one, the default is a new random address.